# Product formatted dimensions display "&times;" instead of "x" in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

I have such a problem with woocommerce plugin. Since last upgrade of woocommerce to last version I can see "×" instad "x" in dimension section in variant product. So I can see for ex. "&15times;15×15cm" instead "15 x 15 x 15cm".

Official support recommends me to disable every plugin (try to plugin conflict) and  activate storefront theme. I trie both of theese solvings and still no success (this means that problem could be in original woocommerce plugin). You can watch screenshot of this issue here:
[image: enter link description here]

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function hooked in `woocommerce_format_dimensions` filter hook to make the changes that you need this way *(in the last line)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'change_formated_product_dimentions', 10, 2 );
function change_formated_product_dimentions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    if ( empty( $dimension_string ) )
        return __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );

    $dimensions = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) );

    return implode( ' x ',  $dimensions ) . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: OK. That worked! Thanks a lot man.This is forced solution by php. Do you know where is source problem of this issue? Is it possible that newer version of woocommerce won't be making this issue?

Comment: @JiříPrek In the official documentation for [`wc_format_dimensions()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_format_dimensions.html#1188-1204) function which is the responsible of that, there is no problems on the code… **But in Woocommerce source code  located inside the plugin on [`includes/wc-formatting-functions.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php#L1235), as you can see there is `' &times; '` instead of `' x '`** … Then you can use this lightweight snippet, that will not affect your shop performances.

Comment: OK I understand. My bet was php file inside plugin structure. But in this case every user who using this version of woocommerce can see this issue on own website. Do I got it right? (my issue was only in variable products-single was ok)

Comment: @JiříPrek Normally `&times;` displays an "x", so in your case there is something else that is making this strange display. It can be your browser or your WP installation (meaning something in the theme, your other customizations or some plugin) …

Comment: I know that usually `&times;` represents "x" letter but I also didn't understand why this formating doesn't change and display in source format. It doesn't make sense to me. Anyway thanks a lot for helping

EDIT: I tried to view this in 2 smartphones and 3 computers- everything was google chrome and in one case Explorer. My there is **easycommerce**. Other plugins was disabled and theme was original and issue still appears-This is reason why I had to ask for help here

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed at code level by Automattic on Nov. 8, 2018. The problem has nothing to do with another plugin. A filter hook hack added to the function.php fix is just more junk code--skip that suggestion. You can either fix it manually or wait until the next update. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/21833  Use this code to fix the file includes/wc-formatting-functions.php: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/21833/files.  Solves the problem completely.